# StreamWriter not closing correctly?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, streamwriter

I'm having some trouble using the StreamWriter class correctly. I have about 10 objects I need to post, but only a couple at a time at most. However, after 2 posts, the third does not go through and times out. I realize this is because the max connections you can have is 2. However, I'm confused as to why I am being stopped after 2 since I (think) I am closing my StreamWriter connection. Here is my code:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("my url"); 
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
//var data = json data

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(data);
    streamWriter.Close();
}
```

I thought the using statement would close it automatically, but it didn't, so I added the Close() line. However, this didn't seem to do anything. The debugger gets stuck on the using line on the third try. If I setServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit to something like 10, everything works, but I'm confused why what I have written doesn't. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's more likely that it's to do with what you do with the *response*.

The `using` statement will close the `StreamWriter`, and you don't even need the explicit `Close` call. However, you *also* need a `using` statement for the response:

```
using (var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
{
    ...
}
```

If you don't have *that*, the connection pool for the particular host will be clogged with connections due to unclosed response.

Comment: I didn't even realize that! I'm still new to this. Thanks a bunch, it works now!